# My Discord Bot Doesnt Go Online, Im using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to many various ways but i dont get the message "Logged in as (bot name)".

```
require("dotenv").config()
const {Client, InstentsBitField, IntentsBitField, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    ],
});

client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

please someone help.

my discord bot doesnt get online.

Comment: Are there any errors? Did you give your bot the proper intents of GuildMembers and MessageContent on the developer dashboard? Try adding a `.catch` to your `Client#login` method and log any errors.

Comment: Replace `process.env.token` with just `token` - it's a JS variable, so should not be passed through env vars. Unless you're going to use that instead of this method. AI generated code?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Looks Goods, double check your discord bot token & if any error shows let as know

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).